# Check one of the list columns is in list of strings in Linq, C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a list A that contains multiple columns and I have another list B consists of strings. I am trying to get list A where column x has value in list b

```
List A - Users
Id  Name   Profession  Age
1   John    Teacher     45
2   Mike    Executive   49
3   Patrick Teacher     34
4   Vinny   CEO         65
5   Sam     Investor    56

List B - ProfessionsList
Teacher
Invester
```

Now I would like my linq query to return three following records

```
1   John    Teacher     45
3   Patrick Teacher     34
5   Sam     Investor    56
```

What do I have for now

```
 users = users.Where(x => x.Profession.Contains(ProfessionsList).ToList();
```

Comment: You want `x => ProfessionsList.Contains(x.Profession)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, you want to check if profession list contains professions you have in list A

```
 users = users.Where(x => ProfessionsList.Contains(x.Profession)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Other possible solution is that by using [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) instead of `Contains` as following:

```
users = users.Where(x => ProfessionsList.Any(p => p == x.Profession)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is **You are checking whether any Profession in `ListA` Contains `ListB`** While you want to check `ListA where column x has value in ListB`, So you should fix like below

```
var users = users.Where(x => ProfessionsList.Contains(x.Profession)).ToList();
```

You can also use [IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it

```
var users = users.Where(x => ProfessionsList.IndexOf(x.Profession) != -1).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Learn AspNet